# Refering to previous value in MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

How I can refer to previous value of MDX measure? For example:

```
A   B
------
1   
2   1
3   2
4   3
8   4
```

It's look very simple, but when I use:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[B] AS(
    [Measures].[A].lead(1)
    )
```

It's gives me value of another measure (for example [Measures].[A2]), not last value from [Measures].[A].

Comment: you should use `LAG` instead of `Lead`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `lag` or `lead` against the members you have `ON ROWS` of the following:

```
A   B
------
1   
2   1
3   2
4   3
8   4
```

... well in the above there is nothing illustrated `ON ROWS` so it could be the following:

```
       A   B
       ------
1Jan   1   
2Jan   2   1
3Jan   3   2
4Jan   4   3
5Jan   8   4
```

So would apply lag or lead to the `CURRENTMEMBER` of the `DATE` dimension as it is `ON ROWS`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[B] AS(
    [Measures].[A].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(1)
    )
```